# Will compilers optimize "strnlen(mystring, 32) > 2" to stop looping as soon as the running length exceeds 2?

Tags: c, optimization

Do modern compilers (or perhaps these have been in place since C89) substitute in *short circuit evaluated* code for cases like the one below during conditional expression evaluations?

```
char mystring[32] = "this is a long line";
if((strnlen(mystring, 32)) > 2)
{
    return 1;
}
```

As in the right operand is taken into account during processing `strnlen(...)`, and the moment the running length of the C string within `strnlen(...)` exceeds the right operand of the outer conditional expression (2 in this case), `strnlen(...)` breaks out?

- Would it have mattered if I hadn't preassigned the string length?
- Would it have mattered if I had removed the parentheses from the **IF** inner expression?
- Would it have mattered if I had switched the operands and the operator to a `<`?

Comment: How would the *compiler* (as opposed to the *linker*) know which version of `strnlen` you are using?

Comment: Short circuiting normally refers to operators that sometimes skip evaluating their operands, such as `&&` and `||`, particularly when doing or not doing so affects the correctness of code. It would be better to think of what you're asking about as optimization.

Comment: you bring up a good point. i'm not to familiar with function versions, but if we were to specify some C version with ```-std```? at this point, I was more concerned with the behavior rather than the specificity in versions. i would appreciate if you could avoid that aspect and excuse my novice behavior for the moment during your answer.

Comment: Why not write the following? `if((strnlen(mystring, 3)) > 2) { ... }`

Comment: @JohnKugelman thank you for your input. okay see now that this is an optimization question. however, what happens during these cases? what if the string was a billion characters and i only needed it be greater than 2 true or false?

Comment: @Chris wow you just offered a great solution i didn't see haha

Comment: @Chris that is another intelligent use of the _n_ function variations

Comment: @JohnKugelman the reason i referred to these as short circuit evaluation is because i was thinking if C had an in-built way of handling these much like it handles the && and ||

Comment: from your perspective, apart from a solution, do languages usually bother with cases like these? for example, pascal and then java adopted strings to have their length query be O(1) rather than O(n)

Comment: `strnlen()` is probably optimized.  You can inline those 3 compares or try your hand at SWAR (http://0x80.pl/articles/simd-strfind.html#swar).

Comment: Re “if we were to specify some C version with `-std`?”: This will not do any good because `strnlen` is not a standard C function. It is a POSIX function. I am not aware of a switch for GCC or Clang that tells them to assume POSIX functions.

Comment: @AllanWind thanks, first time i'm hearing of this i'll look into it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil hmm i was unaware it was a POSIX function. i was just beginning to delve into documentation, but usually took all the standard library and commonly available headers to be of the base language...

Comment: You might also implement your own `compare_strlen_with(const char *str, size_t len)` which only iterates over as much of the string as needed to return `-1`, `0`, or `1`. Then you just need to check for `1`.

Comment: i appreciate the solutions! if you have an answer on the _behavior_ of the presented code along with how the 3 cases would affect the evaluation, if any, please feel free to post an answer!

Comment: @mindoverflow well, here it is - strnlen isn't documented in any standard header. Py POSIX documentaion it's in `string.h` (not a  standard C++ header) and might be in some others. By manpages,  it is accessible only if certain definitions are present, and listed standard is: POSIX.1-2008.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Maybe*, depending on the compiler. Let's look at some examples, compiled with gcc 13.2.0 and clang 17.0.1, both at optimization level `-O3` and [with extensions enabled](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#index-std-1) (note that `strnlen` is POSIX, not standard C).

```c
int p() {
    char mystring[32] = "this is a long line";
    return strnlen(mystring, 32) > 2;
}
```

Both clang and gcc [optimize](https://godbolt.org/z/54s7s4az7) this to `mov eax, 1; ret`. This is because they know the behavior of `strnlen` and can substitute in the return value of the call without needing to evaluate it at runtime. (In gcc this is [implemented via `__builtin_strnlen`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#Other-Built-in-Functions-Provided-by-GCC)).

If the `strnlen` function isn't a known builtin, but can be inlined:

```c
inline size_t my_strnlen(char const* s, size_t n) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i != n; ++i)
        if (s[i] == 0)
            return i;
    return n;
}
int p() {
    char mystring[32] = "this is a long line";
    return my_strnlen(mystring, 32) > 2;
}
```

Here clang [optimizes](https://godbolt.org/z/qPe9TYMqn) to `mov eax, 1` but gcc emits a loop.

Finally, for an unknown predicate that is marked [`pure`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-pure-function-attribute) to tell the optimizer that it has no side effects:

```c
__attribute__((pure)) int f(char);
inline size_t my_strnlen_f(char const* s, size_t n) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i != n; ++i)
        if (f(s[i]))
            return i;
    return n;
}
int p() {
    char mystring[32] = "this is a long line";
    return my_strnlen_f(mystring, 32) > 2;
}
```

gcc again [emits](https://godbolt.org/z/5nzzhMqf6) a loop; clang emits some rather clumsy code (what's up with `ebx`?) that nevertheless shows that it knows that `f` needs to be called no more than 3 times, with the character codes of the first 3 characters - it optimizes out the full string:

```
p:                                      # @p
        push    rbx
        mov     edi, 116 # 't'
        call    f@PLT
        xor     ebx, ebx
        test    eax, eax
        je      .LBB2_1
.LBB2_3:
        mov     eax, ebx
        pop     rbx
        ret
.LBB2_1:
        mov     edi, 104 # 'h'
        call    f@PLT
        test    eax, eax
        jne     .LBB2_3
        mov     edi, 105 # 'i'
        call    f@PLT
        xor     ebx, ebx
        test    eax, eax
        sete    bl
        mov     eax, ebx
        pop     rbx
        ret
```

> - Would it have mattered if I hadn't preassigned the string length?

No, in that case the C language would just set the buffer size to the size of the string literal (string length + 1 for the terminator).

> - Would it have mattered if I had removed the parentheses from the IF inner expression?

No, the optimizer runs on a program representation that does not include these details of syntax.

> - Would it have mattered if I had switched the operands and the operator to a `<`?

Almost certainly not, the optimizer is capable of understanding that these are equivalent.

Comment: For consistency with the POSIX function, the prototype should be `size_t my_strnlen(char const *s, size_t n)`

Answer (score 4):

It says [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) that `strnlen` is a built-in function, so gcc can do optimizations involving the semantics of `strnlen`.

If your string is constant, it can optimize it out (but of course this is just a funny fact; it doesn't really help you).

If your string is not known in advance to the compiler, gcc doesn't do any optimizations. Theoretically, it could inline the function and optimize the resulting code, but in practice, it doesn't happen. You could implement such an optimization by yourself — from what I understand, clang has a convenient language which describes optimizations.

I can't say about other compilers.

You can use the dedicated [godbolt site](https://godbolt.org) to check such things.